# Django password required views

Tags: django, django-views

I have an edit view for editing models objects. I want to make it password protected with a password I generate and put in my model. **I don't want to use django Users**

Let's say I have something like this:

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    ......
    job_uuid = models.CharField("UUID", max_length=36, default=make_uuid)
    password = models.CharField("password", max_length=36)
```

views.py

```
def edit_job(request, job_uuid):
    job = get_object_or_404(Job, job_uuid=job_uuid)
    job_form = EditJobForm(instance=job)
    c = {'job_form': job_form,
    }

    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('jobs/edit_job.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I wanted to protect this URL with the password from the object. I found this app [django-password-required](https://github.com/mikl/django-password-required) but this app uses one password you set in the settings.py

Any easy package or way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a decorator that will check if password access is required for `edit_job` view.

Then decorator can use password from session/cookies to verify the access.
If password does not match or not present, you can redirect to different view to show password form, and store it in session.

Hope this helps.